# how to make a vertically align middle with csss

Tags: html, css

i want a vertically align middle div

text and image are not align

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<span>    text </span><img src="read-mor-but.png" />
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Will you mark answer as accepted if it has solved your problem? so that it might be helpful to other community members!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add `vertical-align:middle` to `img` tag

```
#wrapper img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A6u5D/)

Answer (score 0):

try to add `line-height:100px` too along with your code **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/usx4j/1/)**

css:

```
#wrapper {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:100px;
}
```